# Possible to Divert/Forward Functions in Android?

Tags: java, android, reflection

I just wanted to know if there is any way to divert/forward a **system class's methods**. Means to change it's function while in app.

Example: One of my Jar libraries is using `java.io.File` 's method `length()` several times. I want to edit/code the `length()` (like some kind of inheritance but not really) and make it cache the `length` so speeds up the process.

*Note: It's just an example*

Maybe some kind of reflection am expecting.

Answer (score 0):

No, there's no way to do that.  What you can do is create a new class MyFile that's a subclass of File and override the length function on that.  Since it's a child class, it would even be passable to a function that takes a File object.

Also, I'd check to make sure File doesn't already do this.  I'd also consider what you want to have happen if the file size changes due to it being altered between the time you cache it and the time you access it in the future.

Comment: "if the file size changes due to it being altered between the time you cache it and the time you access it in the future." It's a bad idea if the length changes while in between of sorting because it won't be arranged well, also mis-arrange the list. Despite that i know that way, but i clearly mentioned File is being used by my Jar Libraries so i cant edit my Jars right? All i can do is change what he is calling it possible. Like a place holder or something. (I clearly mention not same as inheritance)